# Programming RCX in 10.9 environment

Tags: rcx

My school has 15 RCX robot kits that this year has just been sitting because all the old computers with OS X 10.4 are now gone and we are using OS X 10.9.  I would like to run the original RoboLab Software (1-2.0) because it is for middle school kids.  The graphic programming interface works great with these students.

Is there anyway I can do this.  I would hate to toss the 15 sets as they are still very usable. We also have 6 NXTs.

What are my options here?

Comment: NXTs can jump to the latest version of EV3 software.  That version is downloadable from Lego.

Answer (score 2):

For the RCX devices, if you want to use the RIS or RoboLab software on OS X, your best solution is to see if a VM image running Windows gives you what you want.

The main problem will be accessing IR Tower: the Mac doesn't have a COM port without a serial dongle (which could be had for cheap, but they can be a pain to use). And a USB Tower (if you have them) may not work in a virtualized environment. You would have to experiment.

Alternatively, you can use something like NQC or LeJOS for the RCX 1.0/1.5/2.x devices (any RCS 1.0 device will accept the latest 2.x firmware) on OS X. This is, of course, very command-line oriented.

Perhaps the latter solution could be reserved for the more advanced coders in the group.

I see that [there is already an answer that enumerates some of the places you might be able to find RIS 2.0](https://bricks.stackexchange.com/a/4455/3971).