# Where can I download the software for old RCX-era Mindstorms sets?

Tags: software, rcx

These days I've been coming across a lot of people who've purchased used MINDSTORMS sets from the RCX era, only to find they didn't come with a CD. And in order to use the set, assuming that using an alternate programming language is not an option, the buyer can either [Buy a CD off Bricklink](http://www.bricklink.com/browseList.asp?itemType=G&catID=631), or find a place to download the software.

While CDs aren't overly expensive, they're going to become harder to come by as time goes on, and being able to download the software is preferable since it's almost instant and doesn't cost money. LEGO technical support representatives have stated over and over again that they don't care about people copying and downloading their old software, so downloading their old software is perfectly legal.

Does anyone know a reliable place to download the software for the Robotics Invention System 1.0, 1.5, and 2.0? CD images are preferable, but working stand-alone installers are valid as well. Extra points to anyone who can also provide a place to download the software for the Vision Command, Ultimate Builders Set, Exploration Mars, Extreme Creatures, and Robo-Sports expansion packs. And super extra special points if someone knows where to get an iso for the Windows XP-specific Vision Command software and the Robotics Invention System promotional CD.

Comment: While you specifically ask for the RIS software, this was not the only software LEGO distributed with the RCX brick. There were also LEGO Education sets marketed to schools that included a graphical programming tool called ROBOLAB, which was an add-on to a program called LabVIEW. [LabVIEW](http://www.ni.com/labview/buy/) is an expensive program, but is available to educators at a discount. The [ROBOLAB Add-on](http://www.legoengineering.com/program/robolab/) is free.

Comment: It is true that that is software packaged with some RCX sets, but I didn't list it here since it was educational software rather than retail software. And like you said, it was an add-on to expensive 3rd party software. Nonetheless, if someone includes a link to download that in their answer, I won't count any points off.

Comment: Something to consider is that LEGO released the RIS software [in different languages](http://www.bricklink.com/search.asp?itemID=46439).

Comment: Quite right. I was thinking about that when I first wrote the question. I guess just it's preferable that the submitted download links are for English versions.

Comment: The real challenge will be installing and running it on modern equipment.

Comment: The simple solution to that is to install it on a virtual machine.

Comment: Nope, there's a simpler solution. On Windows 10 just use the compatibility mode with the software.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've found a seemingly broken website, but from the sources I was able to salvage these addresses, they work just fine (as far as the download goes, I did not check the contents):

- http://www.brickfactory.info/iso/files/9731_lego_vision_command_xp.zip -> German version
- http://www.brickfactory.info/iso/files/9722_extreme_creatures_1.0.zip

Vision Command English:

- https://www.mediafire.com/?xo6xfjvnbzaaf7u

Multi Software Download -> English:

- https://www.mediafire.com/folder/ohsruj4zmjy9g

There are many other downloadables from this site:

- http://biomediaproject.com/bmp/files/LEGO/cds/temp/1349_Lego_Studio_Dutch_XP.zip
- http://www.brickfactory.info/iso/files/1382_lego_studio_sound_fx.zip
- http://biomediaproject.com/bmp/files/LEGO/cds/temp/3804_dutch.zip -> RIS 2.0
- http://biomediaproject.com/bmp/files/LEGO/cds/temp/3804_french.zip -> RIS 2.0
- http://www.brickfactory.info/iso/files/3806-3809_Spybotics_english.zip
- http://www.brickfactory.info/iso/files/8299_lego_submarine.zip
- http://biomediaproject.com/bmp/files/LEGO/cds/temp/8428_Turbo_Command_CD1.zip
- http://biomediaproject.com/bmp/files/LEGO/cds/temp/8428_Turbo_Command_CD2.zip
- http://biomediaproject.com/bmp/files/LEGO/cds/temp/8450.zip -> cybermaster_mission
- http://biomediaproject.com/bmp/files/LEGO/cds/temp/lego_cybermaster_dutch.zip
- http://www.brickfactory.info/iso/files/8547_mindstorms_nxt_2.0.zip
- http://www.brickfactory.info/iso/files/9731_lego_vision_command_xp_french.zip

As for the RIS ISO I've found this torrent but it looks like there is no recent activity, maybe one could ask the once-downloaders to seed for a while?
https://www.demonoid.ph/files/details/2583886/004623788640/

Comment: Not bad. It doesn't completely fulfill all the criteria for any of the stages of thoroughness, but it does cover some of all three. If nobody provides a better answer in the next three days then I'll award the 50 bounty to you.

Comment: Well, I went ahead and awarded the bounty to this question. Not quite ready to select it as the accepted answer, though. I still encourage others to provide a more complete answer if possible.

Comment: Thank you. I have created the answer as a community wiki specifically in order to facilitate future expansion / correction by anyone else.

Comment: StackExchange is the Best. I was astonished seeing that even a Lego site exists!!! I found the software for my old Mindstorms Robotics Invention System 1.5. Running it on a VM with XP and my godchild and mysel are happy!

Comment: These moments are the reason why I love StackExchange :)

Comment: @Daenu: can you please specify which link you used for RIS 1.5? I'm finding all either blocked or broken links here, but my hope is high as you've posted in the recent past :).

Comment: Use the link http://www.mediafire.com/download/rw1k1g5nyjakdp7/LEGO+MINDSTORMS+RIS+v1.5.iso and enter the captcha to authorize download when blocked.

Comment: @user3617389 sry, don't remember. Had to crawl a bit until i found it

Answer (score 4):

There are a lot of ISO files with the Robotics Invention System (RIS) software on them. Here's one link:

http://www.brickfactory.info/iso/

These will only work on Windows.

Answer (score 3):

RIS 2.0 ISO now up on archive.org https://archive.org/details/ris20

Answer (score 2):

I have RIS 2.0 in GERMAN Language, which I backed up for myself and all other old LEGO Fans and uploaded it. I run it on Virtual WinXP, which is set up with Oracle Virtualbox. For the old RCX Tower I have bought USB to Serial Adapter - RS232 Converter and connected it to WinXP.

Here is the Link for German Software : 
https://www.mediafire.com/file/nbinswfcsxfujel/RIS2.ISO/file

Answer (score 2):

there is also coach 5 & 6 software special for education.
from CMA / amstel Institute ( University from Amsterdam). 1999 for the RCX1.0 and the RCX 2.0

https://adoc.pub/handleiding-coach-5-installatie-projecten-activiteiten-funct.html
https://softadvice.informer.com/ext/https_cma-science.nl/Coach-6
https://docplayer.nl/25036978-Installatiehandleiding-coach-6-lite-nl.html
https://student.uva.nl/binaries/content/assets/studentensites/uva-studentensite/nl/a-z/ic/handleidingen-nl-en-en/coach-6-home-handleiding.pdf
http://lkruise.nl/natuurkunde/opdrachten/leerlingbrief.pdf

reminder: not in the lite version and not in coach 7