# Vision Command and Exploration Mars software for Mindstorms RIS 2.0

Tags: mindstorms, software, rcx

I recently bought a set 3804 LEGO Mindstorms RIS (Robotics Invention System) v2.0 very well maintained but did not have the installation CD of the RCX program and IR tower. With some research on the Net, I managed to find the RIS v2.0 software and the expansions Extreme Creatures and RoboSports.

This set also includes the USB Camera from the Vision Command expansion but without the installation CD and the problem is that I can not find the software nowhere. Where can I download the software in English for the 9731 Vision Command and 9736 Exploration Mars??

I found a similar question here which was answered by another user with the links for the download of the software Vision Command but one was in German the other in French.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As it just so happens, I'm physically in possession of an English Vision Command CD. I've uploaded the iso here:

https://www.mediafire.com/?xo6xfjvnbzaaf7u

I didn't upload and post it in that other question you mentioned since I wasn't aware none of the Vision Command ones were English, but I've also updated the answer in that other question with this link for completeness.

Note that this software was originally designed for Windows 98. The very first thing you should do is run the install file in compatibility mode for Windows 98, otherwise you'll get an error telling you that your version of Windows is too new. And if you keep getting warning messages saying that this software has known compatibility issues, click "Continue anyway" for every one of them. I'm also wanting to say that you sometimes get an error when the camera itself is installing. In this event, just keep clicking "ignore" or "retry" or whatever until it finishes. I've been able to get the software to install and run on Windows XP, Vista, and 7, although the camera won't be recognized by your computer if your operating system is 64-bit. I'd be interested in seeing if that driver David Lencher linked you to would fix this problem for 64-bit operating systems.

Comment: Thank you. I have searched for this software since I bought the RIS v2.0 set. Now I'm happy :)

Comment: I managed to obtain also the expansion 9736 Exploration Mars but I lost my installation CD and as the expansion 9731, I can not find the software to download on the Internet. Can you also help me on this?

Comment: I'm afraid that RIS 2.0 and Vision Command are the only RCX-era software I physically possess, so I can be of no more help than anyone else. Sorry.

Comment: Hello again. I managed to obtain the installation CD of 9736 Exploration Mars. I shared on the "Multi Software Download" -> http://bricks.stackexchange.com/questions/4414/where-can-i-download-the-software-for-old-rcx-era-mindstorms-sets

Answer (score 1):

I found this page: http://riskonomics.blogspot.com/2009/06/lego-vision-command-camera-drivers.html

The author says that he was able to get the camera to work with a Logitech Webcam driver is730enu.exe (which is linked on that page).

From the sound of it, the original driver wouldn't do you any good anyway unless you are still running Windows XP.

Comment: Would make sense as under the hood LEGO seemed to use the Logitec cameras for both LEGO Studios and Vision Command.