# LEGO STUDIOS Moviemaker Set

Tags: software

I was offered a set from LEGO STUDIOS line, very well maintained but without his software.

Can someone share the installation CD in English of LEGO STUDIOS 1349 Steven Spielberg Moviemaker Set or where can I download the software in English??

Answer (score 4):

Generally speaking, you should ask LEGO to send you a replacement disc. In 2006 they sent the software without any further cost according to [this forum thread](http://brickfilms.com/topic/lego-studios-moviemaker-software-for-child/).

Note though, the official software is almost 15 years old by now, and so it is likely incompatible with any modern computer. [There is a version that is compatible with XP](http://rec.toys.lego.narkive.com/vMp41y0b/lego-studios-1349-steven-spielberg-software-upgrade), but anyways it is generally accepted [that the official software is far worse than the best generic alternative](http://www.bricksinmotion.com/forums/topic/6871/has-anyone-ever-used-the-lego-studio-software-is-it-any-good-and-if-so/).

Keeping this in mind, I would rather recommend you to look around for other generic video-editing software: [Free software collection of a hobbyist LEGO movie group](http://www.bricksinmotion.com/forums/topic/68/the-free-software-list/)

Answer (score 3):

I do have a copy of that floating around somewhere*, and can attest to the fact that it only worked directly with Windows 98.

LEGO did release an [updated CD for the "Mindstorms Vision Commander"](https://bricks.stackexchange.com/a/4531/56) set that worked with Windows XP that should enable the drivers for the webcam which I also have somewhere*, but I was unable to install the correct drivers for the Camera (effectively a low-spec Logitec webcam iirc) from the install media on a 64 bit Windows 7 machine (I also tried both compatibility settings and Windows XP Mode) - this seems to be a limitation of the Camera.

The software itself was quite good for editing (based on a Pinnacle Software video editor), but the [rendered output was far worse](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZgSFK7qxlKM) than the original/in-app player.

If you have an Apple device, you will get better results from the [LEGO Movie Maker](https://itunes.apple.com/gb/app/lego-movie-maker/id516001587) app, which provides decent live onion skinning in the viewport, as well as a better camera and output. Other devices have other apps available as well.

`*` In this case "in a box in the loft" I think - not sure how accessible it is, but I need to get some stuff down this weekend, so will see if I can dig it out.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to find the English version for Windows XP:

http://www.mediafire.com/download/h88sxgzkfs2278x/studio.iso