# LEGO Studios Movie Maker Camera (1349) (2000)

Tags: programming, software, electronics

A few months back I had purchased the [LEGO Studios Movie Maker Set (1349)](https://brickset.com/sets/1349-1/Steven-Spielberg-Moviemaker-Set) and have been tampering with it, specifically the camera, to see if I can get it to work on my Windows 11 laptop. Was able to download the software off of Internet Archive, yet whenever I plug the camera in it does not respond. My laptop recognizes when the USB is plugged in, yet the movie maker software does not. From what I have noticed it could be the drivers, as whenever I try to update them using Device Manager it seems to not work, assuming it is because how old the camera is. The software itself works perfectly fine; it is just the camera that cannot be recognized on the software. If anyone knows how to solve this issue or has any tips, please let me know!

[image: Picture of the USB camera]

Comment: Do the answers in [LEGO STUDIOS Moviemaker Set](https://bricks.stackexchange.com/questions/4759/lego-studios-moviemaker-set) help you out ? It sounds like it's not trivial trying to get the drivers to work on a modern Windows version. Maybe a virtual machine with either Windows XP or 98 will get you further ?

Comment: Hi, the manual included with the set does not really help me with anything. The drivers within the camera seem to be missing whenever I look up the connection within Devic Manager. Have thought about downloading a version of Win XP or 98 on my Win 11 laptop to see if I could get the camera working from there, but I am not 100% sure where to look.