# Mindstorms Vision Command - what shall I do with it?

Tags: mindstorms

I have a Vision Command camera, bricks and book, still boxed with instructions and a W98 coaster, er I mean CD, and was about to donate it to a charity shop but it seems there's no 64 bit driver for it? Windows can't find one anyway.

I'm not sure it's worth wasting their time with it. I suppose a note saying "not for new versions of Windows" might still attract someone with an older PC but I'm open to suggestions?

Regards

Comment: Have you read this post: http://bricks.stackexchange.com/questions/4529/vision-command-and-exploration-mars-software-for-mindstorms-ris-2-0? Someone says that you can use a Logitech driver to get the camera to be recognized.

Answer (score 2):

I've tried with limited success to get this hardware to work with various systems. There was a single third-party cam driver for OS X that let it be used as a digi-cam. That is, there was no integration with other LEGO software or firmware.

It is some sort of Logitech, but the devil is in the details. There are no modern Windows drivers. OS X is probably no longer a viable option, though I have not checked recently (recently: last 3-4 releases). Linux or BSD is probably where experimentation might pan out.

Even so, getting the camera to work is different than getting it to work with any other era of Mindstorms equipment.

It is essentially abandon-ware or experiment-ware.

My only advice is to give it away or sell it "as-is". I did consider cracking it open and replacing the guts with more modern hardware (perhaps a bluetooth or wi-fi camera to get rid of the tether) but without any integration into Mindstorms, it's just another digi-cam. But at least it could be one that easily attaches to other LEGO.

Answer (score 2):

It is a Logitech Quickcam, and yes, it still works on Linux (I've tried it on ev3dev with my EV3 and Ubuntu 20.04)

Comment: Wow, can't believe somebody else is experimenting with this in the 2020s! Did you have to install anything extra to get the camera working under Linux? What software do you use on Ubuntu to view the camera output?